# Divide Cell Contents into 'n' Equal Values Repeatedly and Re-Distribute into Every 'm'th Cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

This is a follow up question to [Divide Cell Contents into 'n' Equal Values Repeatedly and Re-Distribute into Consecutive Cells](/q/1329292), but in this case I am looking to have the answer re-distributed across a larger range by skipping cells as determined by an inputted value.

The original question was [solved](/a/1329380) by [robinCTS](/u/763880).

**Recap**

In the original question [cameron12](/u/912414) initially had:

```
n=5
0, 0, 0, 0, 1000, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

and they wanted to end up with:

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 0, 0...
```

In my case I am trying to figure out how to do the same thing, but instead re-distribute those values based on an inputted number. For example, for *m* = 2, ie, every 2 months or 2 cells, the output would be:

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 200, 0, 200, 0, 200, 0, 200, 0, 200, 0, 0...
```

For *m* = 3 (every 3 months or 3 cells) it would look like this:

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 200, 0, 0, 200, 0, 0, 200, 0, 0, 200, 0, 0, 200, 0, 0...
```

Let me know if any more clarification is required.

Note: I have been trying to solve it using `MOD()` but it has me stumped.

---

**Update:** Here's a screenshot to help clarify the situation for multiple input values:

[image: Screenshot of Spreadsheet]

For the topmost data row, the $418K on July 1st should be split up and spread out over every *m*=3 months, which should be different to the months from the splits of the $2.5M on September 1st. The output sequence should look like:

```
83000, 0, 500000, 83000, 0, 500000, 83000, 0, 500000…
```

(Note: I rounded the values for easier identification.)

For the second date row,  the $250K on July 1st and the $350K on October 1st should output:

```
50000, 0, 0, 120000, 0, 0, 120000, 0, 0, 120000, 0, 0, 120000, 0, 0, 70000…
```

where the `120000` Is the sum of the July and October splits (`50000+70000`).

Comment: Please [edit] your post & share with us the formula or method you have tried so far,,, since basic issue has been solved by Robin !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I thought my previous formula (see [this revision](/revisions/1659747/2)) would be the simplest possible as it was solving the simplest output scenario given multiple inputs.

Turns out that what is actually required with multiple inputs is for them to be distributed independently of each other. Surprisingly, the solution for this is actually even simpler, *and* has no caveats! So, I've updated this answer with the new formula.

---

You were on the right track in using `MOD()`.

Here's a solution using [the same table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDFlu.png) from [the previous question](/q/1329292), with a value of 5 for *n* and a value of 3 for *m* (stored in `A6`):

[image: Screenshot of worksheet]

Array enter (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) the following formula in `B3` and copy-paste/fill-right into the rest of the table (don't forget to remove the `{` and `}`):

```dart
{=SUM((0=MOD(COLUMN(INDEX(3:3,1):INDEX(3:3,$A$5*$A$6))-1,$A$6))*IFERROR(INDEX(($2:$2),N(IF(1,COLUMN()-(COLUMN(INDEX(3:3,1):INDEX(3:3,$A$5*$A$6))-1))))/$A$5,0))}
```

**Caveats:** None.

---

**Explanation:**

The prettified version of the formula is as follows:

```dart
{=
SUM(
  (0=MOD(COLUMN(INDEX(3:3,1):INDEX(3:3,$A$5*$A$6))-1,$A$6))
  *
  IFERROR(
    INDEX(
      ($2:$2),
      N(IF(1,COLUMN()-(COLUMN(INDEX(3:3,1):INDEX(3:3,$A$5*$A$6))-1)))
    )/$A$5,
    0
  )
)}
```

There are two changes to the formula from [the previous answer](/a/1329380).

Firstly, the second argument of the first `INDEX()` inside the `IFERROR()` has been  modified from

```dart
N(IF(1,COLUMN()-(COLUMN(INDEX(3:3,1):INDEX(3:3,$A$5))-1)))
```

to

```dart
N(IF(1,COLUMN()-(COLUMN(INDEX(3:3,1):INDEX(3:3,$A$5*$A$6))-1)))
```

The formula is a bit easier to understand if, as shown below, you consider that for *n* = 5 and *m* = 3, this is effectively equivalent to:

```dart
COLUMN()-{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14}`
```

Since we are effectively spreading out the split values across more output cells, we need to generate an array of offsets to access the previous *n*×*m*-1, plus the current, input values, rather than the previous array's *n* values.

Note that we are still dividing the input values by *n*, as they are still only split up that number of  times.

The second change is that the (now-modified) array originally inside the `SUM()`, `«15-most-recent-input-splits»`, is multiplied by another array:

```dart
SUM(
  (0=MOD(COLUMN(INDEX(3:3,1):INDEX(3:3,$A$5*$A$6))-1,$A$6))
  *
  «15-most-recent-input-splits»
)
```

Similar to above, for *n* = 5 and *m* = 3, this array is effectively equivalent to:

```dart
  (0=MOD({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14},$A$6))
```

The `MOD()` results in an new array with a zero for the current input cell and every cell that is a multiple of *m* cells to the left, and a non-zero value for all the other cells (for the most recent *n*×*m* input cells).

Comparing this array to zero results in the final array which contains a `TRUE` where there was a zero value and a `FALSE` otherwise.

Since `TRUE` is converted to a one and `FALSE` to a zero when arrays are multiplied, this array is essentially a 'sieve', only allowing through to the `SUM()` the split input values that come from the input cells that are at multiples of *m* away from the current cell.

Hopefully, stepping through the formula in `I3` should make all the above clearer:

- `COLUMN(INDEX(3:3,1):INDEX(3:3,$A$5*$A$6))-1`
  →`COLUMN(INDEX(3:3,1):INDEX(3:3,15))-1`
  →`COLUMN($A$3:$O$3)-1`
  →`{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15}-1`
  →`{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14}`
  =`«offsets-to-15-most-recent-inputs»`
- `COLUMN()-«offsets-to-15-most-recent-inputs»`
  →`COLUMN()-{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14}`
  →`{9}-{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14}`
  →`{9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5}`
- `N(IF(1,{9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5}))`
  →`N({9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5})`
  →`{9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5}`
  =`«column-#s-of-15-most-recent-inputs»`
- `INDEX($2:$2,«column-#s-of-15-most-recent-inputs»)/$A$5`
  →`INDEX($2:$2,{9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5})/5`
  →`{100000,0,0,0,7,0,10000,0,"INPUT","INPUT",#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!}/5`
  →`{20000,0,0,0,1.4,0,2000,0,#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!}`
- `IFERROR({20000,0,0,0,1.4,0,2000,0,#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!},0)`
  →`{20000,0,0,0,1.4,0,2000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}`
  =`«15-most-recent-input-splits»`
- 
- `(0=MOD(COLUMN(INDEX(3:3,1):INDEX(3:3,$A$5*$A$6))-1,$A$6))`
  →`(0=MOD(«offsets-to-15-most-recent-inputs»,3))`
  →`(0=MOD({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14},3))`
  →`(0={0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2})`
  →`{TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE}`
  =`«sieve»`
- 
- `SUM(«sieve» * «15-most-recent-input-splits»)`
  →`SUM({TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE}*{20000,0,0,0,1.4,0,2000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0})`
  →`SUM({1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0}*{20000,0,0,0,1.4,0,2000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0})`
  →`SUM({20000,0,0,0,0,0,2000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0})`
  →`22000`

The `INDEX($2:$2,N(IF(1,«expression»)))` is a required hack<sup>*</sup> in order to force Excel to return an array for `«expression»` since the second argument of `INDEX()` is evaluated to a single value by default. Using just `INDEX($2:$2,«expression»)` in `I3` would result in this evaluation:

- `INDEX($2:$2,COLUMN()-(COLUMN(INDEX(3:3,1):INDEX(3:3,$A$5*$A$6))-1))`
  →`INDEX($2:$2,{9}-(COLUMN($A$3:$O$3)-1))`
  →`INDEX($2:$2,{9}-(1-1))`
  →`INDEX($2:$2,9)` → `100000`

since inside an expression returning a single value, `COLUMN(«multi-cell-range»)` returns the column of the first cell of the range.

The `IFERROR()` is required in case the formula exists in a cell close to the left side of the sheet, resulting in either accessing the row header, or attempting to access a cell to the left of column `A`.

**Notes:**

- The prettified formula actually works if entered.
- The brackets around `($2:$2)` in the prettified version are required to force the `$2:$2` to remain on its own line.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup> The explanation of exactly why the hack works will once again have to wait until I (eventually?) figure it out for myself first ;-)</sub>

Comment: Wow this is incredible! Thank you so much! This is way more in-depth than I thought it was, but definitely makes sense. If you figure out a way to fix the caveat of the 2018 $7 value, definitely let me know, but thank you so much for all your hard work this is unbelievable

Comment: Do you think there is any way to solve the caveat or is that not possible?

Comment: @AustinBurks I haven't really thought through how to solve the first caveat as I sort of assumed that it wasn't what was required. Are you saying  you're interested in this for the output: `0.00`, `2,000.00`, `0.00`, `1.40`, `2,000.00`, `0.00`, `1.40`, `22,000.00`, `0.00`, `1.40`, `22,000.00`, … ?

Comment: My apologies on the confusion, yes that would be more like what I am looking for! In the case of multiple sale inputs, it would be great if they followed the sequence above. I could probably make do as is rn, but if you have a solution or an idea of how to modify it, that would be super helpful

Comment: Either way though you are incredible and thank you so much for your help so far

Comment: I added an edit to the question with an image, so hopefully that clarifies it a little bit more

Comment: @AustinBurks I think I've worked out a way to have all the values start  distributing independently of each other, but it'll have to wait until tomorrow; Its time for sleep now!

Comment: Of course! Sounds great enjoy your sleep! No rush on this I have time

Comment: @burksooner Done: Simpler and with no caveats!!

Comment: YOU ARE A GENIUS. This is so great! It's amazing this is a little simpler, but does exactly what I want it to do!